# Mio A501 Digiwalker drivers for Windows 7 64-bit (build 7100)?

Tags: drivers, installation, windows-mobile

Can anyone recommend how I could go about installing a Mio A501 Digiwalker GPS-capable Windows PocketPC phone on Windows 7 x64 build 7100 (public RC)? When I plug the device into a USB slot, Windows 7 goes through the motions of downloading and installing a driver from Windows Update, but eventually fails to install.

The device isn't even showing up in the Device Manager list of devices for further troubleshooting. Drivers that came with the device on CD are for Windows XP/2000 & Server 2003. The device works fine in Windows Vista 32-bit (Mobile Device Center detects and installs just fine).

Relevant website: http://www.mio.com/sea/gps-navigation-products-a501-overview.htm

**Update 1**: For some unknown reason, the device now gets detected and syncs just fine with the Windows Mobile Device Center, but after syncing it automatically gets disconnected. Does anyone know how to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW I have that phone and it works fine with Windows Vista's Windows Mobile Device Centre.

Comment: Yea, it worked for me after a few tries. Didn't quite manage to figure out what went wrong. Oh well.

Comment: Sometimes there are issues with ActiveSync running on the Mio, so I reboot the Mio and it usually then works okay.